# Let $f $ be $C^{\infty}$ with $f(x,0)=f(0,y)=0\in\mathbb R$. Show $f(x,y) = xyg(x,y)$ for $g\in C^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, smooth-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of class $C^{\infty}$ with $f(x,0)=f(0,y)=0$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. prove that there exists $g: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of class $C^{\infty}$ such that $f(x,y)=xyg(x,y)$ for any $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Since $f$ is of class $C^{\infty}$ then all its derivatives are continuous. I don't know how to prove the existence of the function $g$

Comment: I'd suggest proving that the function is divisible in $\mathscr{C}^{\infty}$ by $x$ (resp. $y$) iff $f(0,\cdot)=0$ (resp. $f(\cdot,0)=0$), which would solve the problem. For the $x$ part, consider e.g. the function $f_1(x,y)=\int_0^1{(\partial_xf)(xu,y)\,du}$.

Comment: Define $g(x,y) = \frac{f(xy)}{xy}$ if $xy \ne 0$ and prolongate it accordingly where $xy =0$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malgrange_preparation_theorem

Comment: @MartinR The two answers given at that link are a way-too-long proof that has problems, and a hint from me. I don't think those answers are a good reason to close this

Comment: I might consider the Taylor remainder theorem to write an explicit expression for $ g(x, y) = f(x, y) / xy $ in terms of $ C^k $ functions, for some fixed (but arbitrary) $ k $.

Comment: @zhw. I have written an answer to the old question.